# How to use async/await with a library that uses an event-based asynchronous pattern?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, .net-4.5, async-await, c#-5.0

I use a library that has an asynchronous method called DoWork(...) that will raise a WorkDone event when the operation completes.

I would like to write a method that calls this library, but instead of maintaining the same pattern I would like my method to be `async` so it can be called with `await`.

In essence, what I am trying to do is:

```
public async Task<Result> SomeMethod()
{
    var result = new Task<Result>();

    library.WorkDone += (data) =>
    {
        result.Result = data;
    }
    library.DoWork();

    return await result;
}
```

(not working because Result is readonly)

Can this be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will build on ws0205's answer:

First, you indicate that you want your method *"to be called with `await`"*. You achieve this by returning a `Task`.

I also think that it's better to make the following adjustments to  ws0205's answer:

```
public Task<Result> SomeMethod() //no async, since we're not awaiting anything
{
   var result = new TaskCompletionSource<Result>();

   library.WorkDone += (data) =>
                                {
                                    result.TrySetResult(data); //just in case 
                                };
   library.DoWork();

   return result.Task; //no need to await - we're returning a Task - let the caller await (or not)
}
```

Comment: Ok, that works as well. I am using this in a web server, can you confirm that this won't block threads even though there is no async keyword?

Comment: @G.Stoynev's right, threads don't be blocked, because you return the `Task`, and those who will use it will need to use the `await` keyword.

Comment: For more information, [see the MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873178.aspx#EAP).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [TaskCompletionSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd449174.aspx):

```
public async Task<Result> SomeMethod()
{
   var result = new TaskCompletionSource<Result>();

   library.WorkDone += (data) =>
                                {
                                    result.SetResult(data);
                                };
   library.DoWork();

   return await result.Task;
}
```